# Variable is used uninitialized in this function

Tags: c++

I have completed the program, but I'm getting one error. it says total, min, hours, sec is used uninitialized in this function. I tried using different variables, and I initialized the variable but it  still didn't work. Can someone help me figure out what did I do wrong. I put `time( total,hours, mins, secs);`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

void time(int, int, int, int); 

int main() 
{ 
 int total; 
 int hours;
 int mins;
 int seconds;
 int secs; 

 cout << "Enter the number of seconds: "; 
 cin >> seconds; 
  time( total,  hours,   mins,  secs); 
 cout << "The number of hours is: " << hours << endl; 
 cout << "The number of minutes is: " << mins << endl; 
 cout << "The number of seconds is: " << secs << endl; 
 return 0; 
} 

void time(int total, int &hours, int &min, int &sec) 
{ 
    int rem1; 
    hours = total / 3600; 
    rem1 = total % 3600; 
    min = rem1 / 60; 
    sec = rem1 % 60; 
    return ; 
}
```

Compiler output:

```
15:38: warning: 'total' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
15:38: warning: 'hours' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
15:38: warning: 'mins' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
15:38: warning: 'secs' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

I have completed the program, but I'm getting one error. it says total,min,hours,sec is used uninitialized in this function. I tried using different variables, and I initialized the variable   but it  still didn't work. Can someone help me figure out what did I do wrong. I put time( total,  hours,   mins,  secs);

Comment: Your declaration of function `time` does not match your definition of function `time`.  This means they are two different functions, and you should get an "unresolved symbol" error.

Comment: `time()` should be called with `seconds` in the `total` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototype is incorrect here:

```
void time(int, int, int, int);
```

It should be:

```
void time(int, int&, int&, int&);
```

Once that is fixed (most of) your warnings should go away. You do still have some other bugs though, e.g. you use `seconds` as your input variable, but you then discard this and instead pass the uninitialised variable `total` to your function - you should probably just be using `total` as your input variable and get rid of `seconds`.

Comment: The warnings may go away but it is still garbage

Comment: now i got this error hours = total / 3600;    total is uninitialized in this function                     int total; note total was declared here

Comment: @programmer1111: re-read the last paragraph of the above answer.